# 3rd order homogeneous differential equation with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

How do I solve the following homogeneous differential equation?

$$x^3u'''-3x^2u''-x(x^2-6)u'+(x^2-6)u=0$$

I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: Write $q=u', r=q', s=r'$ and you will get $y$ system of 1st degree ODEs

Comment: The point $x=0$ is a regular singular point. Try a Frobenius expansion of the form $u=x^\alpha \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let:

$$u(x) = x v(x)$$

- Calculate the first, second and third derivative of $u(x)$.
- Substitute back into ODE and simplify.
- This will reduce the ODE to a form you can work with.